# Can not insert value in the database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can anyone help me?
I trying to add some value in the database, but i can not insert it, i dont know the reason why? Can you help?
i have the right html code, i mean i define all the input in the right name, i dont know why i can not post it in here
My php code like:

```
<?php 
require_once("../../../include/admin/ad_ovhead.php");
require_once("../../../lib/connection.php");
if (isset($_POST["add"])) {
    //lấy thông tin từ các form bằng phương thức POST
    $tend_an = $_POST["tend_an"];
    $ngaybd = $_POST["ngaybd"];
    $ngaykt = $_POST["ngaykt"];
    $mieuta = $_POST["mieuta"];
    if ($tend_an == "" || $ngaybd == "" || $ngaykt == "") {
    echo '<h4 align=center style="color: red;">Vui lòng nhập đầy đủ thông tin</h4>';
    }else if($mieuta ==""){
    //thực hiện việc lưu trữ dữ liệu vào db
    $sql = "INSERT INTO projects(
    tend_an,
    ngaybd,
    ngaykt
    ) VALUES (
    '$tend_an',
    '$ngaybd',
    '$ngaykt'
    )";
    // thực thi câu $sql với biến conn lấy từ file connection.php
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    header('Location:proj_management.php');
    }else{
        //thực hiện việc lưu trữ dữ liệu vào db
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO projects(
        tend_an,
        ngaybd,
        ngaykt,
        mieuta
        ) VALUES (
        '$tend_an,
        '$ngaybd',
        '$ngaykt',
        '$mieuta'
        )";
        mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
        header('Location:proj_management.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Never inserting post values directly, which leads to SQL Injection attacks. Also, always monitor the return values of `mysqli_query()`

Comment: add backticks to your query like `INSERT INTO projects(\`tend_an\`, \`ngaybd\`, \`ngaykt\`, \`mieuta\`)`

Comment: You miss a single Quote at the end of `'$tend_an,`

Comment: VALUES (
        '$tend_an',
        '$ngaybd',
        '$ngaykt',
        '$mieuta'
        )

Comment: Check for Errors after executing a SQL query

Comment: Post your connection code

Comment: Thanks so much i soved my problem

Answer (score 1):

if you are inserting values from variables, remove the double quote in the variables

And if you are declaring an insert query string in a variable,
Declare your insert Query string like this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO projects(
        `tend_an`,
        `ngaybd`,
        `ngaykt`
        ) VALUES ('
        .$tend_an.','
        .$ngaybd.','
        .$ngaykt.',
        )';
```